# unable to get duration for multiple audio files in flutter

Tags: flutter

I've been trying to get the total duration of all the audio files in an array. I'm using AudioPlayer ( https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayer ) library to play the files. To get total duration of the audio files, I wrote this function:

```
calculateTotalDuration() async {
    int count = 0;
    AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

    await Future.forEach(audios,
        (MyAuduoData element) async {
      await audioPlayer.setUrl(element.path, isLocal: true);
      int dur = await audioPlayer.getDuration();
      print("Duration: " + dur.toString());
    });
  }
```

Say, I have three audio files data in the `audios` array. When I run the app in debug mode and put breakpoints in each lines of this function, it shows 3 duration outputs. But when I run normally, I mean without any breakpoints for debugger, it only shows one output. Any solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ForEach has problems with asynchronous tasks.  Use a for loop instead.